# split spaces with a regex only if they are not contained in a substring

Tags: javascript, regex, string, function, split

I should split by spaces (or \r\n\t) a string that could contains substrings

Example:

```
text 'contained in' a string
```

I have tried with a regex like:

```
/[?<!\"\'](\ )*[?!\"\']/g;
```

string.split(regex) should returns:

```
["text", "'contained in'", "a", "string"]
```

.

But it's wrong... I'm freaking from much time to resolve it :@

For now, I made a split function that automatically split by a sepchar if there are out of substrings, but I'm looking for a simple solution with regex, if possible, obviously :P

Comment: What exactly is the result you want to achieve in you above mentioned example?

Comment: this -> ["text", "'contained in'", "a", "string"]  

  spaces contained in substrings does not split

Comment: Are you going to have stuff like `text 'contained in a string's inverted commas' a string`? It's bound to be complicated otherwise.

Comment: Of course, in this case it should be enough use an escape char like \

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
(?:'(.*)'|(\b[\w]+\b))
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/oJ2nQ9

Or even better, rather than using word bounderies (because your string may contain special characters)..  This would be better:

```
(?:'(.*?)'|(?:[\s]*|^)([^\s]+)(?:[\s]*|$))
```

Sample string:

```
text 'contained in' a string-with special's chars.
```

Matches:

```
"text", "contained in", "a", "string-with", "special's", "chars."
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/iP3iJ1

Comment: thank you, with this small modification I can now unsplit by ' or " with  (?:['|"](.*?)['|"]|(?:[\s]*|^)([^\s]+)(?:[\s]*|$))

Answer (score 2):

Try `/([\'\"][^\"\']+[\'\"])|([^\s]+)/g`, simple but works fine.

http://regex101.com/r/hR3bQ8/

You can extract the substring only by using `/([\'\"][^\"\']+[\'\"])/g`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you were *trying* to use lookarounds like this:

```
/(?<!\"\')(\ )*(?!\"\')/
```

However, JavaScript does not support lookbehinds (`(?<=...)` or `(?<!...)`) so you'll need a different strategy. Any capturing groups within the pattern you're splitting by will be returned in the result array, so splitting like this will get you close to the result you want:

```
var input = "text 'contained in' a string";
var output = input.split(/('[^']*')|\s/);
console.log(output); // ["text", undefined, "", "'contained in'", "", undefined, "a", undefined, "string"]
```

Now the only problem is what do you do about those `undefined` and empty strings? You can use the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method from ES5, like this:

```
var input = "text 'contained in' a string";
var output = input.split(/('[^']*')|\s/).filter(function(s) { return s && s.length; });
console.log(output); // ["text", "'contained in'", "a", "string"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in Javascript:

```
var s="text 'contained in' a string";
s.split(/ +(?=(?:(?:[^']*'){2})*[^']*$)/g);
//=> ["text", "'contained in'", "a", "string"]
```

Regex basically uses a lookahead to make sure there are even number of quotes following a space.